# How to fetch relation table one to another via serializer? django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two serializers for two models (`Blog` and `User`). This is one to many relation, User can have one or more Blog. But a Blog should belong only to one User.

The goal is I want to include `blogs` model if I will fetch the `user`. vice-versa

```
API: /user/1
response: 
{
    name: 'John Doe',
    blogs: [                     <========== include
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'First Blog',
        },
        ... so on, so forth
    ]
    ... more field
}
```

The current situation is, the `UserSerializer` can incude the `blogs`. But in `BlogSerializer` it cannot include the `user` since "BlogSerializer" is not defined.

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = "__all__"
    
    user = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    blog = BlogSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

---

Do you have idea how to fix or achieve this? I'm new in Django, I would appreciate any comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches that you can use. But, here is a simple example:

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="blogs"
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
```

serializers.py

You can enhance that approach by using only BlogSerializer with [`dynamic fields`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields), but you will need to overwrite your view `.list`method:

```py
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ["id", "user", "title", "body"]

    def get_user(self, obj):
        return model_to_dict(
            obj.user, 
            fields=("id", "username", "email")
        )


class UserNestedBlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ["id", "title"]


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    blogs = UserNestedBlogSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "blogs"]
```

Note that in `BlogSerializer` the nested user object is not serialized, but transformed into a dictionary using django forms `model_to_dict` helper method, exactly the same as writting:

```
def get_user(self, obj):
    return {
        'id': obj.user.id,
        'username': obj.user.username,
        'email': obj.user.email
    }
```